# while loop and arithmetic operator

Tags: c, while-loop, arithmetic-expressions

```
int i = 5; 

while(i>5)

printf("%d",i);
```

prints nothing.

```
int i = 5;

while ( 5<i<10 )
{
printf("%d",i);                      
i++;
}
```

prints  5

In both the cases shouldn't be the result "prints nothing" .  Because 5 is not less than 5.

Comment: `5 < i < 10` should not be valid in C. It's supposed to be `i > 5 && i < 10`.

Comment: @John, I agree.  I am now curious how the compiler would parse such a condition.

Comment: Note that Python does support `5 < i < 10` to mean what you'd like, but the vast majority of programming languages interpret it as `(5 < i) < 10` and when the result of a comparison is `0` or `1`, that gives an indefinitely long loop because both `1 < 10` and `0 < 10` are true and the first term only evaluates to either `0` or `1`.

Comment: `5 < i < 10` is valid. That's one of the great things about C, the rules for expression parsing are simple and consistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C integer is used as a boolean: `0` is `false`, everything else is `true`. 
As @JonathanLeffler noted (see his comment below), in C99 and C11 there is a standard boolean datatype, but it also expands to integer constants (`0` and `1`). [Link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/stdbool.h.html).

When you write an expression like `5 < i < 10`, it is treated like `(5 < i) < 10`, where `5 < i` is a boolean expression, which returns `0`. So you get `(0) < 10`, which is true, that's why the loop's body is executed.
In order to make the loop condition correct, you shoould use something like:

```
while (5 < i && i < 10)
```

Comment: +1 You beat me by like 3 seconds hahah, perfect answer!

Comment: In C99 and C11 there is `_Bool` as a standard built-in type, and `<stdbool.h>` which defines `bool` as a synonym for `_Bool` (and `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`, and `__bool_true_false_defined` as `1` too).